# Excel - When saving sheet1, write certain cells to sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to vba and need your assistance in writing a code that will do the following

1) I have a workbook titles "workbook.xlms" which I have saved in my documents

2) The workbook has got 2 sheets, namely sheet1 and sheet2

3) Sheet1 has predefined fields such 
as "name", "surname", "address", "contact", "social security", "race" and so on

4) After filling in the predefined fields with required data and clicking save, some (or all) of the fields must be written to empty row on sheet 2 sheet2.

5) If new information is filled in on sheet1 and the social security number entered is already registered in sheet2, then new data must not be written to sheet2 (To avoid duplicates).

I do not have any code to share with you and am hoping you can help

Answer (score 0):

Start by recording the copy/paste portion of the macro and view the code. See if you can modify that to suit your needs. Post back here with what you tried if you still can't make it work.

Comment: Hi Kyle, I am not too sure I follow you. I do not ha any vba code or macro. I would like someone to help me with a sample code so I can amend to meet my requirements. What do you mean by "Start recoding the copy/paste portion of the Macro and view the code"?

Comment: This forum is not a place to have people write code for you for free. There are likely many folks here who do so professionally. In order to get responses, it would be better if you posted code and explained what you had tried. Many others would also recommend you try to record the macro first and then try to adjust it to suit your needs. If at that point you have questions, please post back here and folks would be glad to help.